# Enter triggers html button click with javascript that has a specific value

Tags: javascript, html, button

Because we use orbeon xforms, we don't know the id of the button tag.
What we would like is the Enter key to trigger a button that contains a certain string value.

If my form contains a Check button like so:

```
<button id"random">Check</button>
```

I would like my javascript button to trigger it with something like:
find the button that has value "Check" and click it when Enter is pressed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Updated code**, since I didn't see your markup (which contained `<button>` instead of `<input>`)

I would use JQuery here since selecting the buttons you are looking for could be more difficult using Pure JS only.

Something like this should work:

```
$(
    function(){
        $(document).keydown(function(){
             if (event.keyCode == '13') {
                 event.preventDefault();//stop what normally happens..
                 //..like submitting a form maybe
                 //$("input[type='submit'][value='Check']").click();
                 $("button").each(function(i){
                  if($(this).text() == "Check")
                  {
                     $(this).click();
                  }
                 })
             }
        });
    }
);
```

With markup like this:

```
<button id="random" onclick="alert('clicked 0');">Check</button>
<button id="random2" onclick="alert('clicked 1');">Something else</button>
<button id="random3" onclick="alert('clicked 2');">Third Button</button>
```

See Demo : http://jsfiddle.net/giddygeek/Caxae/3/
(Click/Focus on the result pane and hit the Enter key)

Comment: Thanks for your help. I miss one thing though; he "random" is really generated randomly, so I don´t know what the id of the button is. if($("#random") is therefore not possible.

Comment: @user761411 how is random generated, php? asp.net? You have to have a way to target the button by class or id. (Maybe you could generate a class for the button and then filter by that like `$(".myclass)` or you will have to target all buttons `$("button")`.

Comment: It´s randomly generetad by orbeon xforms, a apache tomcat webapp.  I think I want to target all buttons (maybe in an array) and then filter out the one I need that tests positive to value == "Check". Do you happen ot know how to do that? (btw, if I hit Enter in the jsFiddle, nothing happens, right?)

Comment: thanks a lot; works like a charm after I figured out what was wrong (I think);       $(document).keydown(function(){
-->       $(document).keydown(function(event){